# Redirecting IE6 users to a specific page using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, internet-explorer-6

I'm tired of fixing my wordpress site so that IE6 users could view it properly. It's nothing more than wasting my time. I have 2-3 IE6 visitors daily after all.

I believe there is a way to detect if visitor is using IE6 and redirect them to a specific page via .htaccess. But I can't figure out the bullet-proof method.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get a lot of the information you need for this from here: http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/ - great reference with examples.

Answer (score -1):

After doing some research for the last couple of days, I've come across the solutions presented [here](http://evansims.com/6032/using-htaccess-to-redirect-obsolete-browsers/) which, based on my experience, is the bullet-proof solution.